ZFS Snapshots empty - what am I missing
I am having problems with ZFS Snapshots (on an Ubuntu 20.04 server).
I am using zfs-auto-snapshot to keep incremental backups of snapshots, but the problem appears even with manual snapshots.
I can see a list of snapshots when I do a "zfs list -t snapshot".  Some sample output includes:
NAME                                                           USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
[snipped]
zfspool/noderedVM@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-07-01-1811          8K      -     15.2G  -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-05-01-1811    265G      -     1.96T  -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811    189G      -     1.97T  -

However when I go to (for example) /zfspool/.zfs/snapshot/zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811# it shows only top level directories with no files in them.  The non-snapshot versions of these directroies  have a lot of files in them.
The properties for the snapshot are
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   type                        snapshot                    -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   creation                    Sun Jun  2  6:11 2024       -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   used                        189G                        -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   referenced                  1.97T                       -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   compressratio               1.00x                       -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   devices                     on                          default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   exec                        on                          default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   setuid                      on                          default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   createtxg                   41735311                    -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   xattr                       on                          default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   version                     5                           -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   utf8only                    off                         -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   normalization               none                        -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   casesensitivity             sensitive                   -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   nbmand                      off                         default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   guid                        8971539913121518305         -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   primarycache                all                         default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   secondarycache              all                         default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   defer_destroy               off                         -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   userrefs                    0                           -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   objsetid                    21173                       -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   mlslabel                    none                        default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   refcompressratio            1.00x                       -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   written                     283G                        -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   clones                                                  -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   logicalreferenced           1.90T                       -
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   acltype                     off                         default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   context                     none                        default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   fscontext                   none                        default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   defcontext                  none                        default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   rootcontext                 none                        default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   encryption                  off                         default
zfspool/serverbackups@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-06-01-1811   com.sun:auto-snapshot-desc  -                           local

The problem persists regardless of whether the snapshot was created/managed with zfs-auto-snapshot or manually.
So related questions -
Should I be able to see the files in the snapshot "directory"?  If so, what can I do to work out why I can't?     If not, how do I make the snapshot information visible?

The problem turned out that I was looking in the wrong place.   I should have looked in
/data/serverbackups/.zfs/snapshot/zfs-auto-snapshot-monthly-2024-06-01-1811
